# How is it possible that Ansible loop items be referenced by variables outside the looped task?

Tags: ansible

I have a number of tasks that all need to refer to the same object where the object name is modified by a loop item.

The object name is complex and may be subject to change in future script versions and I do not want to have to go through each task changing the name. So I want the object name to be defined in the top-level vars. But this means that the top-level var definition needs to reference a loop 'item' outside of the loop itself. I expected it to throw an error saying that the 'item' is not defined but I was pleased to find that it did not.

I guess that Ansible must be evaluating the top-level variables within each task at which point the 'item' would be valid. Please can someone point me to the documentation that explains this variable evaluation process?

Example:

```yaml
    - hosts: all

      vars:

        ObjectName: "ObjectInMode-{{ item }}-WithComplexName"

      tasks:

      - name: Perform Function 1
        Function1:
          ObjectRef: "{{ ObjectName }}"
        with_items:
          - Mode1
          - Mode2

      - name: Perform Function 2
        Function2:
          ObjectRef: "{{ ObjectName }}"
        with_items:
          - Mode1
          - Mode2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Lazy Evaluation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-lazy-evaluation).

> In general, Ansible evaluates any variables in playbook content at the last possible second, which means that if you define a data structure that data structure itself can define variable values within it, and everything “just works” as you would expect. This also means variable strings can include other variables inside of those strings.